# Bootstrap navbar doesn't collapse on phone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have used the carousel example on Bootstrap3 to make a simple gallery website. On a desktop, it appears as I want, and shrinking the browser causes the navbar to collapse as expected. But it won't collapse on the phone. Instead the whole menu appears as a small version of the desktop view. From reading the docs, I thought it would start collapsed on the mobile view by default.

Since I followed the example code closely and all the bootstrap nav examples appear closed, I'm not sure what piece I'm missing. The site is up: http://artbymanisha.com

Comment: Your page is `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` and a bunch of frames. Maybe start there...

Comment: Interesting...the site is a subdomain of another domain on go daddy. That is what is adding the weird frames. The html I uploaded is all html 5. If I go to the full path from the main domain, where my site name is just a subfolder, than it works as expected. Perhaps I have to move the site up to it's own top-level domain. I will search godaddy forums for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following meta tag to in the `<head>` section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: thank you for that suggestion, but that tag is already present in the head of all pages.

Comment: From the url you provided (http://artbymanisha.com) it is not present in the head of the page. It may be present in the head within the frames on the page, but I dont think browsers will respect meta tags within frames.

Comment: I had an old hosting account on go daddy. changing plans with a different way of rendering subdomains ensured it wasn't in a frame. this comment was the clue.